# TouchableOpacity button with an icon inside doesn't triggers in the white space

Tags: react-native, expo, native

I've made a component for doing an ImageButton using TouchableOpacity. Inside on it, I usually put a fontawesome and a text. The problem is that the press is only triggered if I push in the centre of the button (right on the fontawesome).
Another problem, but I think it's linked to the first, is that the animation of pressing, doesn't trigger if I press the icon in the centre.

For a recap:
If I don't click the icon in the button, for example the white space of it, I see the pressing animation but the onPress isn't triggered.

If I click the icon in the button, for example the font awesome, I don't see the pressing animation but the onPress is triggered.

The component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Style} from './IconButtonStyle';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const IconButton = (props) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={!props.style?Style.button:[Style.button,props.style]} onPress={props.onPress}>
        <View>
            {props.icon}
        </View>
        <View>
            <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)

export default IconButton;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just realized that I was messing with the caller component. I put the onPress on the image instead on the IconButton component.

Answer (score -1):

Ive tested your code it looks ok : [see snack](https://snack.expo.io/GpbqYnAlP)

Comment: can i ask for what is the -1??